# laptop brightness (need help !)

Tags: laptop, brightness, acer

I want to set a limit for brightness in my laptop.
when i reduce to 0 it turn screen off in contrast windows reduce it to visible brightness.

This stop me from switching to Linux i need help.

Desktop environment: KDE
Laptop: Acer E5 575

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: 19.04 ....  i have the same issue with most distro except elemtaryOS